# vba macro: Alternate value display on the loop and limiting selection on curren region

Tags: excel, vba

I created a list of numbers on 1st sheet then on 2nd sheet I created some details where one of the cell will get the value of the cell on the 1st sheet(thru loop)

My script is working but got some issues:
- It gets the value of the 1st row but also gets the value on displayed on the 2nd row.
- It  exceeded the number of Loops based on the number of rows on my 1st sheet.
- It's overrides the formula concatenate on my cell.
- It doubles the spaces after pasting

Codes:

```
    Public Sub Number()

        Dim i, Lastrow As Integer
        Dim valueCT As String

        Worksheets("Sheet2").Select    
        Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

        For i = 1 To Lastrow

            Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
            Range("C2").Select
            Range("C" & i + 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i + 1).Value
            Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
            Selection.Copy

            Range("C" & i + 2).Value = Range("C" & i + 1).Value




            Range("C500").Select
            Selection.End(xlUp).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        Next

    End Sub
```

Number List

Column A - 1st Sheet

```
    Number
    2845
    2846
    2847
    2848
    2849
    2850
    2851
```

Second Sheet column C:F , 2 rows
With formulas  on 1st row cell  "=" and concatenate on 2nd row cell

```
    2845        AAA BBBB    BBBCCC
    2845BBBCCC  AAA BBBB    BBBCCC
```

My expected result is to display all numbers that included on my list
then copy only the first selection on the current region of the 2nd sheet

expected result:

[image]

```
    2845    AAA BBB CCC
    2845AAA AAA BBB CCC
    2845BBB AAA BBB CCC
    2845CCC AAA BBB CCC

    2846    AAA BBB CCC
    2846AAA AAA BBB CCC
    2846BBB AAA BBB CCC
    2846CCC AAA BBB CCC

    2847    AAA BBB CCC
    2847AAA AAA BBB CCC
    2847BBB AAA BBB CCC
    2847CCC AAA BBB CCC
```

Current/ Actual result: 
        2845    AAA BBB CCC
        2846    AAA BBB CCC
        2847    AAA BBB CCC

```
            AAA BBB CCC
    2845    AAA BBB CCC
            AAA BBB CCC

    2845    AAA BBB CCC
    2846    AAA BBB CCC
    2846    AAA BBB CCC


    2845    AAA BBB CCC
    2846    AAA BBB CCC
    2847    AAA BBB CCC


    2845    AAA BBB CCC
    2846    AAA BBB CCC
    2847    AAA BBB CCC
```

Comment: your question is very unclear... can you rephrase the question?

Comment: @Guy Louzon, on my second sheet there u will see the 2 records both of them are using the 1st value on my 1st sheet w/c is 2845, I used equal sign and concatenate. I want to loop that process but got some issues with my codes it displayed alternate value on 2nd  sheet and paste mutiple values due to current region it captures the new value added  everytime it loops.

Comment: Your loop isn't doing anything. Notice you never use your variable `i` inside the loop. That means your loop is just doing the exact same thing over and over.

Comment: @urdearboy..thanks I forgot.. I will update my codes..thanks

Comment: after @urdearboy 's comment, is the problem solved ?

Comment: Not yet , still coding ..

Comment: @Guy Louzon, I updated the code but still got some issues

Comment: @urdearboy I updated the code but still got some issues

Comment: Maybe try taking screen shots. It's hard to visualize what you are trying to do.

Comment: @urdearboy , done addign screenshot